# Validating YAML file in PhpStorm

Tags: yaml, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a project where YAMLs are used (among other use cases) for storing synonym lists. A file may look a little like this:

```
- "streifen,gestreift"
- "fleeceoverall,fleeceanzug"- "federball,badminton"
- "hochgarage,parkgarage"
```

In this case `- "federball,badminton"` is on the same row as `- "fleeceoverall,fleeceanzug"` which causes the build of the application to fail with an error stating

> Unexpected characters near "- "federball,badminton".

I tried to configure a code style profile for code inspections as mentioned here in the PhpStorm documentation:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/customizing-profiles.html?keymap=secondary_default_for_macos

But I don't know what to adjust here. I using the IDE-Standard which looks like this for wrapping and braces (which I guess is what I'm looking for ;) :
[image: Wrapping and Braces Config for code style]

I also took a look at validating my YAML against a JSON file as mentioned here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/yaml.html# but ultimately I don't understand how this works :/

So I guess I'm a little lost on how to avoid the errors at build time beforehand and would love some advice!

Comment: I couldn't find a way to achieve that as well. Please submit this request to the tracker, I hope the YAML subsystem dev knows better 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA&c=Type%20Feature&c=Subsystem%20Lang.%20YAML&c=Assignee%20Alexey.Merkulov